# Converting existing code to Span<T> seems to be slower?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

Given Visual Studio 2019, .NET Framework 4.7.2 project (console application for testing).
Nuget package System.Memory installed to get Span.

Experimenting with the new Span/ReadOnlySpan in order to improve performance in other projects. I've setup a simple piece of code:

```
    public class Tester
    {
      public string ParseNameSubstring(string name)
      {
        var firstNullIndex = name.IndexOf('\0');
        return (firstNullIndex == -1) ? name : name.Substring(0, firstNullIndex);
      }

      public ReadOnlySpan<char> ParseNameSpan(ReadOnlySpan<char> name)
      {
        var firstNullIndex = name.IndexOf('\0');
        return (firstNullIndex == -1) ? name : name.Slice(0, firstNullIndex);
      }
    }

 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var foo = "foo bar \0 blabla";
      Tester t = new Tester();
      Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
      sw.Start();
      string str = t.ParseNameSpan(foo.AsSpan()).ToString();
      sw.Stop();
      Console.WriteLine(str);
      Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
      sw.Restart();
      var str2 = t.ParseNameSubstring(foo);
      sw.Stop();
      Console.WriteLine(str2);
      Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

output:

```
foo bar
19
foo bar
0
```

Is this the correct usage of Span/ReadOnlySpan ? As it seems to slow down a lot (probably with the .AsSpan() and .ToString())?

Is the implicit casting to string not available in .NET Framework 4.7.2 or am I missing a nuget package?

**update**: indeed, not a correct benchmark, but is this the correct usage of span?

**update2**: 
short summary:

- Use .NET Core / .Net Standard, as .NET Framework has less optimizations.
- Don't use .ToString(), work directly with ReadOnlySpan where possible.

Comment: Note that `Span<T>` is faster in .NET Core than it is in .NET Framework: Core contains runtime changes to properly support `Span<T>`

Comment: Always use Benchmark.net for testing: don't try and do it yourself with stopwatches.

Comment: You can't time such a short operation effectively. You should time a loop calling it several million times.

Comment: Also note that you're negating any advantage of using `Span<T>` by then calling `.ToString()` on it. So you're going to get an allocation of a new string either way, `Span<T>` is just a more roundabout way of getting it. The advantage of `Span<T>` comes from *not* doing that -- you can get away *without* creating an entirely new `string` containing your substring, and *just* use the `Span<T>` as a pointer into your original string

Comment: @canton7 can you share a code example?

Comment: "*indeed, not a correct benchmark, but is this the correct usage of span?*" -- per my previous comment, **no**. As I said, the advantage in your scenario comes from the fact that you can just use the `Span<T>` as a lightweight pointer into your original string, **without** having to allocate a whole new string. Calling `ToString()` on it immediately negates this

Comment: @juFo Sure, don't call `ToString()`. Do you have a more complex scenario you want a code example for?

Comment: Note that all this depends on new overloads for a lot of operations that use Span instead of string or an array. Without using those you end up basically allocatiing new objects anways all the time.

Comment: If I don't call ToString()  I have "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.ReadOnlySpan<char>' to 'string'.

`string str = t.ParseNameSpan(foo.AsSpan());`

Comment: @juFo Right, assign it to a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` and not a `string`. The point here is that you **don't need to** allocate a new string! There are lots of new APIs which can take a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` as well as a `string`

Comment: ok I get it.  as requested a more complex scenario with subarrays: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lmgDZq

Comment: @juFo Can you post an example which compiles and runs? That means we have an actual common startup point from, when showing how to speed things up. Note also that you'll probably need to move to Core to get new APIs which take Span/ReadOnlySpan

Comment: @canton7 https://dotnetfiddle.net/KrWc3z

Comment: @juFo Something like this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/S2LvTL

Comment: @juFo Note that this is on the whole very similar to your version which just uses an array: you avoid allocating an intermediate array in all but the `Encoding.GetString` case, and there's an overload of `Encoding.GetString` which lets you avoid it in that case as well. In this usage, `Span<T>` is just a bit easier than passing an array, offset, and count around all over the palce